# Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `nested.col`. i `nested.col = purrr::map(...)`. x no applicable method for 'tk_make_future_timeseries'

Tags: r, mutated, groupwise

I tried to execute the code below and I'm getting error message
Here is the code:

```
full_data_tbl <- merger %>%
  select(outcome, date.y, crime_numbers, sentiment) %>%
  
  # Apply Group-wise Time Series Manipulations
  group_by(outcome) %>%
  future_frame(
    .date_var   = date,
    .length_out = FORECAST_HORIZON,
    .bind_data  = TRUE
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
 

   
  # Consolidate IDs
  mutate(outcome = fct_drop(outcome))
```

Error message:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `nested.col`.
i `nested.col = purrr::map(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'tk_make_future_timeseries' applied to an object of class "character"
i The error occurred in group 1: outcome = AntiSocial.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please provide a ``dput()`` of your data.